# Python checking integrity of gzip archive

Tags: python, gzip

Is there a way in Python using gzip or other module to check the integrity of the gzip archive?

Basically is there equivalent in Python to what the following does:

```
gunzip -t my_archive.gz
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oops, first answer (now deleted) was result of misreading the question.

I'd suggest using the `gzip` module to read the file and just throw away what you read. You have to decode the entire file in order to check its integrity in any case. https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html

Something like (Untested code)

```py
import gzip
chunksize=10000000 # 10 Mbytes

ok = True
with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
    try:
        while f.read(chunksize) != b'':
            pass
    # the file is not a gzip file.
    except gzip.BadGzipFile:
        ok = False
    # EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
    # a truncated gzip file.
    except EOFError:
        ok = False
```

I don't know what exception reading a corrupt zipfile will throw, you might want to find out and then catch only this particular one.

Comment: After looking around I came to the conclusion that this is the only reasonable way of checking the archive in python so I will accept your answer although in general this is a bit CPU consuming which is something I wanted to avoid...

Comment: The error is `except zlib.error:` also you can shorten the try line to just `while f.read(chunksize):` without the `!= ''`

Comment: It's better to assume `ok = False` and only return `True` if you succeed. Currently other exceptions will lead the user to believe the gz is fine even if it's not.

Comment: As written it will crash out on any other exception since they aren't caught.

Answer (score 1):

you can use subprocess or os module to execute this command and read the output. something like this

Using os module

```
import os 
output = os.popen('gunzip -t my_archive.gz').read()
```

Using Subprocess Module

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(["gunzip", "-t", "my_archive.gz"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
```

Comment: The point is I don't want to use external command. I would like to achieve this in pure Python

Comment: you did not clarify "the point" in your question.  The answer gives you "a way in Python using gzip or other module to check the integrity of the gzip archive" that you ask for.  Be more clear next time if you need "pure" python.